# I am getting an error "The method show(FragmentManager, String)"

Tags: android

I am getting an error

> The method `show(FragmentManager, String)` in the type `DialogFragment` is not applicable for the arguments `(FragmentManager, String)`

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "missiles");
    }

    public boolean onCreateOtionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As you're using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`, you should pass to `show()` an instance of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` which can be queried using an `getSupportFragmentManager()` call. Hope this helps.

Comment: No. I am also using it. But still have a problem.

Comment: One more question, even after adding support api's, my app still does not look like Version 4.0 app. Still looks like gingerbread which my phone has. Is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: @user1767451, Support library is designed to let developers use new APIs on older Android versions, not for making the application look the same on all API versions.

Comment: @user1767451, Actually your Activity class should extend FragmentActivity rather than simple Activity to allow you use Fragments.

Comment: So, what should i do to make an ver4.0 holo look like in 2.3.6??

Comment: @user1767451, This question is a too broad to be answered in a comment. Search the net, ask another question here if you won't find any solutions. And please accept the answer if you've found it helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Am using alertdialogbuilder with alert dialog for datepicker i need to support from api8.Its showing everything is fine i can click and select date and set its setted.when i click and change the date and press mobile back date is changed to string format set to textview i hope u can understand

Answer (score 30):

The problem is because you need to be using the support package's FragmentManager but you are using the native FragmentManager when you call getFragmentManager(). Try calling getSupportFragmentManager() when initializing your variable fm

you also have to make sure that you include DialogFragment from the Support package and not from the native package.

You can do that by importing,

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Answer (score 19):

Even i had the same problem when running the code in gingerbread. But works fine for ICS. The solution is,

instead of this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
}
```

use extends FragmentActivty

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.app.FragmentManager`.

Then you should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` but not `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 3):

I got this when opening a `DialogFragment` even though I was not using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`. I had to call `getActivity().getFragmentManager()`, because `getSupportFragmentManager()` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnselectDate:
         DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
         newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
         break;

         default:
         break;
     }
}
```