# Google Play Services example: "connectionResult cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, google-play-services

when I'm trying to follow the example on how to check if Google Play Services is installed I receive the following error: "connectionResult cannot be resolved" in the line inside servicesConnected method

```
int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();
```

What can be missing? I'm copying and pasting it.
I'm following the example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Amazing that they still haven't fixed it yet. Just wasted ten minutes on this.

Comment: They still haven't fixed it.

Comment: And I have found more errors in the getting location updates example.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's a bug in the example. Use this instead:

```
        } else {
        // Get the error code
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                resultCode,
                this,
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Also their servicesConnected() doesnt have a return statement ,what a sham.

Comment: Yeah... I reported all these issues as a bug to the google documentations team. Hopefully they do something about it.

Comment: What is resultCode and CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST

Answer (score 1):

the solution to where it said there was a missing return was to add return false at the end of the else so example:

else
        {
            // Get the error code

```
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                resultCode,
                this,
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {
            // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment =
                    new ErrorDialogFragment();
            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "Location Updates");
        }
        return false;//THIS NEEDS TO BE FALSE 
    }
```

Comment: Also, if you use the above code and the.show method reports an error with the existing arguments, make sure you are using the correct DialogFragment for the arguments; `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175713/i-am-getting-an-error-the-method-showfragmentmanager-string))