# Error Google Login on Android

Tags: android, google-signin

my app said:

> Google play services is not available. this application will close

The code that I am using is https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android

Any suggest?

Comment: It seems you're trying in an emulator. Try in a real device instead. Latter surely will have Google Play Services installed.

Comment: i am trying in a device :(

Comment: Are you sure that Google play services are installed there?

Comment: In devise? I dont know, how can I know?

Comment: If it has Google play store installed then you can be sure that they're installed. Also... Did you declare Google play services as dependency on the gradle file?

Comment: In dependency I have: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Comment: Do you get an exception in logcat?

Comment: Google Play services error could not be resolved: 17

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303941/google-play-services-example-connectionresult-cannot-be-resolved)?

Comment: No entiendo bien que es CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST.

Comment: Yes, I do. But i'm not sure if its permitted another language than english here. Google those errors, you have all questions here on Stack Overflow already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you are checking that GooglePlayServices is installed on the device.  I don't see a check in the code you linked to.

[This webpage](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/google-play-services-setup.html)  describes how to verify that GooglePlayServices is installed on a device and how to handle failures. The information is not completely current, but still provides a good outline of the processing.  The  [GooglePlayServicesUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil) class provides methods for checking if PlayServices is installed, and showing a dialog to allow the user to install it, if it is missing.

Some of the code from the webpage:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            showErrorDialog(status);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private void showErrorDialog(int code) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this, REQUEST_CODE).show();
}
```

Comment: Activity lifecycle method `onStart()` is called before `onResume()`.  You are calling `connect()` in `onStart()`, so it is called before `checkPlayServices()`, which is in `onResume()`.

Comment: ok, this code change my error. No I have ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4

Comment: I think that is [SIGNIN_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED).  If you update your code at pastebin, I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I play some codes here and give you suggestions:

```
  strings.xml:

 <string name="lbl_play_service">This application needs Google Play Service, you must install it first.</string>
    <string name="play_service_url">market://details?id=com.google.android.gms</string>
<string name="play_service_web">https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms</string>

Some javas:

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayService();
}

/**
 * To confirm whether the validation of the Play-service of Google Inc.
 */
private void checkPlayService() {
    final int isFound = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isFound == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
       //Device has updated version of play-service.
    } else {
       //You need to store to update play-service.
        new Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.application_name).setMessage(R.string.lbl_play_service).setCancelable(
                false).setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_service_url)));
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e0) {
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_service_web)));
                    try {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        //Ignore now.
                    }
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: "new Builder" dont found

Comment: I copy your code and IDE said "Cannot resolve symbol Builder"

Comment: @christianrusso it makes an AlterDialog