# Using DialogFragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

### I am learning to use DialogFragments

---

*In my main activity in a condition i have*

```
MyAlertDialogFragment alert = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alert_Dialog");
```

**MyAlertDialogFragment.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import com.example.findmybuffet.R;
    public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          OnClickListener positiveClick = new OnClickListener() {   
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Application finishing ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();    
           }
          };

          OnClickListener negativeClick = new OnClickListener() {   
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "No option selecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
          };

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
          builder.setMessage("Do you want Yes or No ?");
          builder.setNegativeButton("No", negativeClick);
          builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", positiveClick);
          builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
          Dialog dialog = builder.create();
          return dialog;
         }
    }
```

---

**my problem**::

- In the line `alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alert_Dialog");`
- I am getting error as  `The method show(FragmentManager, String) in
  the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments
  (FragmentManager, String)`
- How to resolve this so that i am able to pop the fragment

Comment: post your imports also...are you using support library?

Comment: I guess answer by @sebastian Bianchi will solve your issue. Try that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175713/i-am-getting-an-error-the-method-showfragmentmanager-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`, you should pass to `show()` an instance of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` which can be queried using an `getSupportFragmentManager()` call instead of  `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Also one more mistake i was doing was ..... MainActivity extends activity .... i had to change to MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

Answer (score 2):

Replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`.