# show.(getFragmentManager) with extends Fragment not FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I've stumbled across a problem that I need help with.
I have a tab layout with ViewPager in which i define three different tabs. FragmentTab1, FragmentTab2,  FragmentTab3. 
In my FragmentTab3 I want to use a TimePicker. For this I have defined a TimePickerFragment.java class; seen below:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
   TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

private TimePickedListener mListener;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    // when the fragment is initially shown (i.e. attached to the activity), cast the activity to the callback interface type
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        mListener = (TimePickedListener) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " + TimePickedListener.class.getName());
    }
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{
    // when the time is selected, send it to the activity via its callback interface method
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    mListener.onTimePicked(c);
}

public static interface TimePickedListener
{
    public void onTimePicked(Calendar time);

    View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Okey. So in my FragmentTab3.java file I try to use the following code:

```
 import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.app.TimePickerFragment.TimePickedListener;

public class FragmentTab3 extends Fragment implements TimePickedListener {

private TextView mPickedTimeText;
private Button mPickTimeButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab3.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container, false);

    //Skapar en ListView och kopplar till listview i xml
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    //Arrayen som listan kommer ta värden ifrån
    String [] items = new String[]{"Me", "Testing", "Grid", "View"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); 

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Kopplar objekt-textView till det i xml
    mPickedTimeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_picked_time);

    //Kopplar objekt-knapp till det i xml
    mPickTimeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_pick_time);

    //Skapar en setonclicklistener som säger vad som ska hända när knappen trycks
    mPickTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            DialogFragment picker = new TimePickerFragment();;
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);
}

@Override
public void onTimePicked(Calendar time)
{
    // display the selected time in the TextView
    mPickedTimeText.setText(DateFormat.format("h:mm a", time));
}
```

}

So my problem is this. In this code snip:
    picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

I get the error: **The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String")**

Now I know this can be solved by extending FragmentActivity instead, but I don't want this since my ViewPagerAdapter.java will not be able to return fragmenttab3. Which puts me in a kinda Catch-22 position.

How can I solve this problem without extending FragmentActivity??

Thanks for all the help I can get. Been running around in circles for a couple hours.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175713/i-am-getting-an-error-the-method-showfragmentmanager-string/13175747) you can find a similar question and answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time looking for the answer to this today. I'm not sure the proper wording/lingo how to describe whats happening, but placing getActivity().getFragmentManager() will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this as well and I got no errors but the app crashed when I clicked the button which initiates the dialogfragment