# How to pass alert box value to fragment

Tags: java, android

I have two java file one is fragment and another one DialogFragment. In my app i show alert box with radio button. If user choose anyone option, i want to pass that item to fragment(Address Fragment). I wrote some code its show alert box. but, i can't pass that item to Address Fragment..

Please anyone help to me!

My code here...

AddressFragment.java:

```js
public class AddressFragment extends Fragment implements RadioListAlert.AddressListener {

    int position = 0;

    EditText line1;
    EditText line2;
    EditText landmark;
    AutoCompleteTextView cityText;
    EditText zipcode;
    Spinner country;
    Spinner state;
    RadioGroup tag;
    Button savaddr;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_address, container, false);

        savaddr = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addrsave);
        tag = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        line1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.line1);
        line2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.line2);
        cityText = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_autoCompleteTextView);
        zipcode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
        country = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.countrySpinner);
        state = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.stateSpinner);
        landmark = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.landmark);

       

        // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_autoCompleteTextView);
        // Get the string array
        String[] city = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city);
        // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);

        textView.setAdapter(adapter);


        savaddr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String addr1 = line1.getText().toString();
                String addr2 = line2.getText().toString();
                String addr_city = cityText.getText().toString();
                String addr_zipcode = zipcode.getText().toString();
                String addr_country = country.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String addr_state = state.getSelectedItem().toString();

                //Field Validation

                if (Utility.isNotNull(addr1) && Utility.isNotNull(addr2) && Utility.isNotNull(addr_city) && Utility.isNotNull(addr_zipcode) && Utility.isNotNull(addr_country) && Utility.isNotNull(addr_state)) {
                    if (Utility.line2_validate(addr2)) {
                        if (Utility.line2_validate(addr_city)) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            new RadioListAlert().setListener(this).show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");// I got error in this line setListener(this)


                        } else {
                            cityText.setError("Enter valid City");
                        }
                    } else {
                        line2.setError("Enter valid Address");
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please fill the form, don't leave any field blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void itemClicked(String text) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_android);

        /** Setting the selected android version in the textview */
        tv.setText("Your Choice : " + text);

    }
}
```

RadioListAlert.java:

```js
public class RadioListAlert extends DialogFragment {

    CharSequence[] tag = { "BMW", "AUDI", "MERCEDES", "FERRARI", "SKODA" };
    private AddressListener addressListener;
    private String itemClicked;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Tag Your Car").setSingleChoiceItems(tag, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tag[which],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        itemClicked = (String) tag[which];
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (addressListener != null)
                    addressListener.itemClicked(itemClicked);
                //to dismiss the dialog after user choose an item and click ok, you can also add some validation before dismissing the dialog
                dismiss();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void setListener(AddressListener addressListener)
    {
        this.addressListener = addressListener;
    }




   public interface AddressListener
    {
        void itemClicked(String text);
    }
}
```

I got an error in this line in Address Fragment:

new RadioListAlert().setListener(this).show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");
especially,  .setListener(**this**)

Its throw an Error:

```js
setListener(RadioListAlert.AddressListener) in RadioListAlert cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)
```

Please anyone help me!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

> setListener(RadioListAlert.AddressListener) in RadioListAlert cannot
>   be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Due to passing onClick method context to `setListener` method but required is context of class which is currently implementing `AddressListener` interface:

```
new RadioListAlert().setListener(AddressFragment.this).show(
                        getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");
```

Comment: If i put like i got an error in same line in show method. (i.e) Cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String)'

Comment: @Appu: Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Already i tried that.. But i got the same error in show method

Comment: @Appu: What u have tried ? problem is same see following post [I am getting an error “The method show(FragmentManager, String)”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175713/i-am-getting-an-error-the-method-showfragmentmanager-string)

Comment: Already tried getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()... But i got the same error in show method

Comment: @Appu: ok try it as `RadioListAlert objRadioListAlert=new RadioListAlert();objRadioListAlert.setListener(AddressFragment .this);objRadioListAlert.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");/ `

Comment: One more doubt, If i want pass same item (which one select from that radio button list) to another two fragments means what i do

Comment: @Appu: if posted problem in question is solve then close this question by marking answer as right if this answer help you in fixing issue and for other issues kindly make separate question on SO.Thanks